# Joint probability of geometric random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

> $X$ and $Y$ are geometric, independent random variables with parameters $x$ and $y$ respectively. Use their joint P.M.F. to compute an approximate summation for $P(X<Y)$.

I've setup the problem: $\sum_{i=1}^j \sum_{j=j}^\infty x(1-x)^{i-1} y(y-1)^{j-1}$

But I have no idea how to simplify further from here.

Comment: `X and Y are geometric, independent random variables with parameters x and y respectively.` .......... This is most unsavoury notation. If $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, such that $x$ and $y$ are realisations of those random variables, then you cannot use $x$ and $y$ to denote the parameters of the distribution. Try $p$ and $q$ for the parameters ...

Comment: And the notation $\sum_{j=j}^{\ldots} \ldots$ is a bit inconvenient too...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a geometric random variable $Y$ with parameter $y$, 
$$\begin{align}
P\{Y > n\} &= \sum_{i=n+1}^\infty P\{Y = i\} = \sum_{i=n+1}^\infty y(1-y)^{i-1}\\
&= y(1-y)^n[1 + (1-y) + (1-y)^2 + \cdots ]\\
&= y(1-y)^n \times \frac{1}{1-(1-y)}\\
&=(1-y)^n.
\end{align}$$
Actually, the end result is more easily derived by arguing that the event
$\{Y > n\}$ occurs if and only if the first $n$ trials ended in failure,
and the probability of this is just $(1-y)^n$.
Regardless of which way you computed $P\{Y > n\}$, you can compute 
$$P\{X = n, Y> n\} = P\{X = n\}P\{Y > n\} = x(1-x)^{n-1}(1-y)^n$$ and
hence
$$\begin{align}
P\{X < Y\} &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty P\{X = n, Y > n\}\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty x(1-x)^{n-1}(1-y)^n\\
&= x(1-y) [1 + (1-x)(1-y) + ((1-x)(1-y))^2 + \cdots\\
&= x(1-y)\times \frac{1}{1 - (1-x)(1-y)}\\
&= \frac{x(1-y)}{x+y-xy}.
\end{align}$$
This answer too has a nice interpretation. Let us carry out the
$n$-th trials simultaneously. Then, we can ignore all instances
in which failures were recorded on both trials -- the next pair of
trials must be conducted -- and concentrate on the very first time
that success occurred on at least one of the paired trials, possibly
on both trials.  *Conditioned on at least one success*, an event
of probability $x+y-xy$, (remember $P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A)P(B)$
for independent events?), the probability that $X < Y$ is just the
probability that $X$ occurred and $Y$ did not, which is $x(1-y)$. Thus
we have
$$P\{X < Y\} = \frac{x(1-y)}{x+y-xy}, ~~ P\{X > Y\} = \frac{(1-x)y}{x+y-xy}, ~~
P\{X = Y\} = \frac{xy}{x+y-xy}$$
without any need for summing series or indeed without even writing down
the joint pmf etc.